# Views Module load all unwanted field value with field_sql_storage_field_storage_load

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view

I am anoid by Views module, it load all field value by `field_sql_storage_field_storage_load` for each one but not only selected into field displaying. check below :

**Content type definition**
[image]
**Views definition**

[image]

I'm using Devel module to display queries onload and it display `field_shouldnotloaded` queried but i don't need it ! So, Views load all field , if you have 100 fields and want to display only one , you'll have 100 queries performed for 1 value to display => 99 useless..

This is a bad thing for drupal performance and slow displaying (i have varnish and memcache). This issue appears from recently update version of views.

```
$ drush status
 Drupal version                  :  7.43-dev
 [...]

$drush pm-list | grep views
 Chaos tool suite  
 Views content panes (views_content) Module  Not installed  7.x-1.9
 Views    Views (views) Module  Enabled        7.x-3.13
 Views    Views UI (views_ui)
```

If anyone have an idea to up performance or fix this issue ? 
Thanks you :)

**EDIT**

The issue spotted ! Views use `entity_load` into `views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc` => function `post_execute`

This part must be rewrite to limit data loaded instead of all of fields !